# wifi failed to start with Arch Linux on laptop

Tags: arch-linux, wifi

I just installed Arch Linux.

Wifi worked fine for me on installation but as soon as I rebooted, I received failure messages when trying to connect to my router.
When trying to access my router through `wifi-menu`, I receive:

```
Job for netctl@wls1\x2d2WIRE740.service failed. See 'systemctl status netctl@wls1\x2d2WIRE740.service and journalctl -xn' for details.
```

`systemctl status netctl@wls1\x2d2WIRE740.service` says:

```
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemmd/system/netctl@.service; static)
Active: inactive (dead)
Docs: man:netctl.profile(5)
```

`journalctl -xn` says:

```
-- Unit netctl@wls1\x2d2WIRE740.service has begun starting up.
Jan 01 06:40:43 termin01 network[2002]: Starting network profile 'wls1-2WIRE740' ...
Jan 01 06:40:43 termin01 network[2002]: The interface of network profile 'wls1-2WIRE740' is already up
Jan 01 06:40:43 termin01 systemd[1]: netctl@wls1\x2d2WIRE740.service:main process exited. code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 01 06:40:43 termin01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Automatically generated profile by wifi-menu.
```

Comment: did you try a second or third time? sometimes I find that that helps.

Comment: I use netctl and it works fine for me, better even than wicd. I use netctl and netctl-auto to automatically connect to an available network

Comment: Just a guess but netctl conflicts with networkmanager. You need to stop the networkmanager service, if you have it enabled.

Comment: What's the output of `ip link` and `systemctl --failed`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the profile you are trying to connect to is not in range, or arch is not able to connect to it. Perhaps you should take a look at [the documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netctl#Automatic_switching_of_profiles) and try to configure it again. I currently use it, but it doesn't connect to random networks if they are open, it only connects to recognized SSID's that I have a profile for.